# Retrieve the div content using extjs

Tags: extjs3

I have a div:

```
<div id="content1">This is a div content</div>
```

Using **extjs** I have to retrieve the content(html) of the div `content1`.

I tried   `var c1 = Ext.get("content1").innerHtml;`

But not working..

Answer (score 0):

```
var c1= Ext.fly("content1").innerHtml;
```

you can read about fly [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.html#method-fly)

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code snippet:**

```
Ext.fly("content1").dom.innerHTML;
```

[Working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ibv)

Hope this will help/guide you.